# Float to Date time

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am having an issue when trying to bulk insert 
I can only get it to work with a format file with it saying that the birthdate column is a float and putting it in a temp table but I am wondering if it is possible convert the birthday back to a datetime and insert it into the table from the temp table

```
CREATE TABLE CSVTempData
(
    MEMBERNUMBER float
      ,[FIRSTNAME] varchar(255)
      ,[MIDDLENAME] varchar(255)
      ,[LASTNAME]varchar(255)
      ,[BIRTHDATE] Float
      ,[GENDER] varchar(255)
      ,[MARITALSTATUS] varchar(255)
      ,[OCCUPATIONINDUSTRY] varchar(255)
      ,[OCCUPATIONTITLE]varchar(255)
      ,[ADDRESS1]varchar(255)
      ,[ADDRESS2]varchar(255)
      ,[CITY] varchar(255)
      ,[STATE] varchar(255)
      ,[POSTALCODE] float
      ,[HOMEPHONE] varchar(255)
      ,[CELLPHONE] varchar(255)
      ,[WORKPHONE] varchar(255)
      ,[EMAIL] varchar(255)
      ,[ALTERNATEEMAIL] varchar(255)
      ,[OPEN_DATE] Float
      ,[MARKETINGOPTION] varchar(255)

)



insert into SEV.dbo.MembersNew

select MEMBERNUMBER, FIRSTNAME ,MIDDLENAME,LASTNAME,  
cast  (cast (cast (Birthdate as int) as varchar (8)) as  datetime,   
GENDER ,MARITALSTATUS  ,OCCUPATIONINDUSTRY  ,OCCUPATIONTITLE,ADDRESS1,ADDRESS2,
      CITY ,STATE ,POSTALCODE,HOMEPHONE ,CELLPHONE,WORKPHONE ,EMAIL ,ALTERNATEEMAIL, 
      cast (cast (cast (Open_Date as int) as varchar) as datetime,   
      MARKETINGOPTION 

from CSVTempData
```

Comment: show some samples and desired results

Comment: please show your Code and Clear the Question.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (Seems like a product specific issue.)

Comment: Code added and SQL 2012

Comment: why is the column birthdate a float anyway? your select is casting the birthdate back to datetime.. if it needs to be a int.. like say 2018117.. you would be better to do this select convert(char(10),getdate(),112) some sample data and desired results would REALLY help your cause!

Comment: I have to do it that way because if I set it to datetime I get a mismatch error everything time with the format file

Comment: I would focus on fixing that mismatch error so that you can keep date formatted as date.